# How can I show the previous step value in next step?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have created a multistep webform and it has 5 steps. is it possible to get the previous step field value/data in the next step?
for example, I have a field select list field (key = select_your_data_type) in step 4 and on step 5 show the selected field value?

Answer (score 5):

Look into the computed twig element of webform
You can access the values of data.name_of_field with that

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
HOOK_form_alter(array $form,FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
```

check if `$form_id` equals your specific form (form's machine name) and validate if current page is page where you want to display data ('*step_5*' is wizard's page machine_name).

```
if ($form['progress']['#current_page'] === 'step_5')
```

get values from **$form_state**

```
$form_state->getValue('select_your_data_type')
```

and you can set form elements via

```
$form['elements']['page_5']['field_i_want_to_set_in_page_5']
```

or via

```
$form_state->set('field_i_want_to_set_in_page_5', $my_value);
```

or course do not forget to print **field_i_want_to_set_in_page_5** somewhere on page 5.